# Layout positioning problem with Custom SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Hi everyone i've been trying to make this work for quite a while and i feel stuck, i found a [component](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/03/29/widget-slidingdrawer-top-to-bottom/) on web wich is pretty nice, it allows me top to bottom sliding, the default sample is pretty easy the bar goes on top and the goes down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_open"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/open"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/default_feed_detail" android:id="@+id/txtDetailNews" ></TextView>

    <it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        my:direction="topToBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handle"
        my:content="@+id/content">
        <include
            android:id="@id/content"
            layout="@layout/pen_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/handle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
    </it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And it renders like this quite nicely:

[image]

But now i want to have a header image between the text and between then the custom slidingdrawer it just not render the text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_open" android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/open"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/header" android:src="@drawable/header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageView>




    <it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
        xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:id="@+id/drawer" my:direction="topToBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        my:handle="@+id/handle" my:content="@+id/content">
        <include android:id="@id/content" layout="@layout/pen_content" />

        <ImageView android:id="@id/handle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
    </it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_below="@id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/default_feed_detail"
        android:id="@+id/txtDetailNews"></TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and now the text is gone.... any suggestion with Relative Layout, or If anyone has an idea or component so it can be done easly that would be great too thanks!!

**Edit**

I found something interesting with the hierarchyviewer using the following layout to arrange the components:

```
<it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer
    xmlns:my="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/it.sephiroth.demo.slider"
    android:layout_above="@id/txtDetailNews"
    android:id="@+id/drawer" my:direction="topToBottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    my:handle="@+id/handle" my:content="@+id/content">
    <include android:id="@id/content" layout="@layout/pen_content" />

    <ImageView android:id="@id/handle" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/sliding_drawer_handle_bottom" />
</it.sephiroth.demo.slider.widget.MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer>
```

it seems that the components that are inside the Drawer are being render and take all the space as shown here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i had to do a little workaround with this since the content on the background took the space, and the Textview was giving up its space what i did was the following:

I place the TextView after the header imageView with a paddingTop of a 100dip.

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/default_feed_detail"
    android:id="@+id/txtDetailNews" android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="@id/header" ></TextView>
```

Then on the MultiDirectionalSlidingDrawer i set the content with a `android:layout_above="@id/txtDetailNews"`

And that pretty much solve the problem rendered the sliding between the Content and the header, Thank you all for helping me out... Specially Nathan Fig you earn those 50 man (y)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really need to proof-read your questions. You would probably have had more response by now if you had fixed some very basic grammar mistakes and added a few clarifications to what you wrote.

Here are a couple things to try: move the TextView above the sliding drawer in the XML, as you did in the first layout. Leave the android:layout_below="@id/drawer" attribute- but if it does not work, try removing that.

Try that, we'll go from there.

Comment: it doesnt work because it can't find the drawer id yet, it display the following message: 
"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_below' with value '@id/
 drawer')."

Comment: Ah my bad- of course that would be the case. Remove that attribute then, see what happens. Try adding layout_above="@id/txtDetailNews" to the drawer if that doesn't work. I'm just shooting ideas out there- observe behavior, try to get an idea of what's going on. But don't spend too much time guessing- have you taken a look at hierarchy viewer? http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: updated with the hierarchyviewer i found something odd the Drawer panel is taking all the space isnt a way with the relative layout to say that when a components is not render the other take its space?

Comment: I'm not sure but this may just mean that items contained in a sliding drawer are already in the space they will occupy, just invisible. So seeing the sliding drawer as taking up that much space may be the way a hierarchy view would normally look.

Comment: When you run the app are you able to open the drawer and see the contents? Also, where are you setting the text color? And lastly- when you opened hierarchy viewer, where did it say the text is?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="@id/header"` on the last TextView.

Comment: nothing the text its render and the header too but not the drawer beside it also overlay the header to the text :|